# How to get valid response from Google Speech to Text API?

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-speech-api, google-apis-explorer

I'm recording the user's audio through the laptop mic and I'm trying to convert what they said to text using Google's Speech-to-Text API. However, I keep getting back an empty ( { } ) response.

After recording the audio using navigator.getUserMedia, I create a audio blob and base64 encode it since that's what the API requires for the audio content. With the config parameters below, I then post to the recognition endpoint but get back the empty response. I'm not sure where I'm going wrong.

I've already tried other encodings (LINEAR16, OGG_OPUS, etc.) but I'm still getting back an empty response.

```
        const audioBlob = new Blob(audioChunks, { 'type': 'audio/wav' });
        const audioUrl = URL.createObjectURL(audioBlob);
        const audio = new Audio(audioUrl);
        //audio.play();

        var encodedAudio = btoa(audioUrl); // encode to base 64
        console.log(audioBlob);
        console.log(audioUrl);
        console.log(encodedAudio);

        document.getElementById("screen_div").innerHTML += "<audio controls src=\"" + audioUrl + "\"></audio>";

        var params = {
          "config": {
            "encoding":"FLAC",
            "sampleRateHertz": 16000,
            "audioChannelCount": 1,
            "languageCode": "en-US"
          },
          "audio": {
            "content": encodedAudio
          }
        };

        var xhrSpeechToText = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhrSpeechToText.open('POST', 'https://speech.googleapis.com/v1/speech:recognize');
        xhrSpeechToText.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + accessToken);     
        xhrSpeechToText.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");       

        xhrSpeechToText.send(JSON.stringify(params));
        xhrSpeechToText.onload = function() {
            var xhrTextResponse = JSON.parse(xhrSpeechToText.response);
            console.log(xhrTextResponse);
        }
```